# Count number of elements in a column greater than x but smaller than y

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to count the number of elements in column `'xyz'` which are smaller than `x` but larger than `y`.

```
a= df['xyz'] 
df[1/3 < a < 2/3].count()
```

However, this gives me:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: `np.sum((df['xyz'] > y) & (df['xyz'] < x))`.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here to give a definitive answer

Comment: is `df` a pandas data frame or a list? can't distinguish

Comment: Thank you! df is a data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a= df['xyz'] 
df[(a < 2/3) & (a > 1/3)].count()
```

Answer (score 2):

Subsetting your dataframe is not necessary. Just sum a Boolean series:

```
res = df['xyz'].between(1/3, 2/3, inclusive=False).sum()
```

Chained comparisons such as `x < a < y` work with regular Python scalars, not with Pandas objects, which require vectorised operations.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you the df where it's true:

```
mask = (df['xyz'] > min) & (df['xyz'] <= max)
df = df[mask]
```

then:

```
len(df) or df.count() or df.shape[0]
```

or just:

```
  sum(mask)
```